# JSF Ajax events work only once on Safari

Tags: ajax, safari, jsf-2

I've noticed that, in my application, the Ajax events work only the first time when using Safari (they work correctly on IE and FF). After some debugging, I've noticed that the problem is related with the onevent attribute.
In my tags I've the following:

```
<f:ajax render="@form" onevent="loader" />
```

If I don't declare the **loader** function, the events work (but I loose the effect provided by the function), but as soon as I declare **loader**, even if completely empty, it only works the first time:

```
function loader(e) {}
```

At first, I thought the problem might be on the code I've on the loader method, but, like I said, it also happens with an empty body. If I remove the method, it starts working.

Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Kind regards,

Carlos Ferreira

Comment: What JSF impl/version exactly? Tried the latest?

Comment: @BalusC I'm running this on GlassFish 3.0.1, with Mojarra 2.0.2.

Comment: This is *relatively* old (over a year). [Mojarra is currently already at 2.1](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html). Lot of JS-related bugs have been fixed. Give it a try. I however don't guarantee that it does fix your particular problem, hence not posting it as an answer.

Comment: I'm downloading v3.1 and give it a try, I'll give some feedback later.

Comment: Well, I've tried the latest version and the problem persists... :(

Comment: I'd post an issue at http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES